# can ice40 be dynamically reconfigured?

Tags: fpga, self-modifying

On a lattice ice40 is there any way, apart from "reboot", for the fpga to dynamically reconfigure itself, ie self modify the fpga on the fly?
(I realise this would be very bad practice)

I assume the fpga has on it some configuration microloader? maybe even a low level cpu??